# Getting cropperjs to post cropped image to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, cropperjs

I'm trying to integrate [Chen Fengyuan's 'cropperjs'](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) into a website I'm designing and I have the interface working fine with the crop box doing as it should. However, my limited knowledge of Javascript and jQuery has brought me to a standstill.

What I would like to do is click on a button under the canvas (similar to the Get Cropped Canvas button) and have the cropped image posted to the server using a simple jQuery AJAX call.

I don’t need a preview of the cropped image as the image is already previewed on the interface. However, I can't seem to do this successfully because every time I try and use the methods provided in the 'cropperjs' documentation, I get a browser errors like:

> ReferenceError: cropper is not defined

I've tried various methods and have seen a lot of solutions online but I just can't seem to get it right. I know I'm doing something very wrong but because I don't understand Javascript and jQuery well enough. I'm really struggling. The documentation mentions initialising with the Cropper constructor but I don't know how to do this and I'm guessing this is where my problem is? Can anyone help?

Comment: Firstly, paragraphs break up a wall of text and make it much easier to read. Secondly, please include your code in the question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put any code as I was trying so many different ways. I've managed to solve this issue now and have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to painfully solve this myself so for anyone who's interested, here's the code I used:-

```
var $image = $("#image");
        var cropper = $image.cropper();
        var baseURL = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host;
        var pho_id = $("input[name=pho_id]").val();
        var mem_id = $("input[name=mem_id]").val();
        var photopath = $("input[name=photopath]").val();
        $image.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
                formData.append('pho_id', pho_id);
                formData.append('mem_id', mem_id);
                formData.append('photopath', photopath);
                $.ajax(baseURL+'/path/', {
                    method: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function () {
                      console.log('Upload success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                      console.log('Upload error');
                    }
                });
        }, 'image/jpeg', 0.8);
```